# Set port for DNS on OS X

Tags: macos, networking, mac, dns

I'm using OS X 10.9.1 and I want my DNS lookups to happen on port 54 instead of 53.

First I looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/resolver.5.html) but the file states:

```
This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
this Mac OS X system.
This file is automatically generated.
```

So my question is: Can I edit some other file in order to make sure the look ups happen on a specific port? I know I can do this at the router level on DD-WRT but I want this to happen on the OS.